# How can i use react-router Link efficiently?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

when I use the Link in the navbar in react it takes me to the suggested URL again and again even if I am present at that home ,how can I redirect conditionally such that if I am on the home page then after clicking the home button again, I will not go to the home page again

```
<Link className="link" to="/leaderboards">
      <Home/>
</Link>
```

Comment: paste some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<NavLink />` component to redirect to other routes and set the active className as disabled class.

App

```
  <NavLink to="/" className="link" activeClassName="disabled-link">Home</NavLink>
```

CSS

```
.disabled-link {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use a `Link`. You just specify a pathname in a `Link` component, and manage your paths-components inside a `Router`.

Now you just render a `<Home />` component always, hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The open Github issue (at time of writing) for this is here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5362

To reiterate the solution [here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/routing-issue-in-react-react-router-creates-duplicate-history-to-the-same-location/423089/2), you can create a hook for to prevent similar locations from being pushed consecutively:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function useLocationBlocker() {
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(
    () => {
      history.block(
        (location, action) =>
          action !== "PUSH" ||
          getLocationId(location) !== getLocationId(history.location)
      );
    },
    [] // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  );
}

function getLocationId({ pathname, search, hash }) {
  return pathname + (search ? "?" + search : "") + (hash ? "#" + hash : "");
}
```

To reproduce, click the Home link more than once and notice that you can press the back button the same number of times. (https://codesandbox.io/s/r0wXp0Njw?file=/index.js)